# Understanding how is a field theory with a negative mass dimensional coupling becomes nonrenormalizable?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

A quantum field theory with a negative mass dimensional coupling (or equivalently, an operator having mass dimension $>4$) is nonrenormalizable. Therefore, it must be the case that (i) the divergences arising from loop contributions cannot all be absorbed into the redefinition of fields and the couplings in the Lagrangian, (ii) measurement of a finite number of parameters is not sufficient for predictions at higher and higher energies. Is there a simple way to understand this?

My guess is that a finite number of counterterms is not sufficient. If that is true, it will be enlightening to understand why there will not be a finite number of counterterms.

Comment: The point is essentially that, if you have vertex whose coupling has negative mass dimension, you can construct loops that lead to effective vertices of even lower dimensions where (almost) each of the "new" effective vertices formally diverges. And you can go on like this forever. This is different from the case of a theory where all couplings have nonnegative mass dimension. To cure this, you'd need infinitely many counter terms, and the theory is no longer predictive.

Comment: @marmot It's not entirely true that non-renormalizability of a theory precludes it from being predictive. While staying below the UV completion scale, theories, in the form of effective field theories, can be (and are) quite predictive, and at times easier to work with than their renormalizable counterparts.

Comment: @Avantgarde Sure, effective theories are to some extent predictive, but I don't think your phrase "not entirely true" is appropriate here. "Not entirely true" means just "wrong", which my statement is not (IMHO). My comment refers to the question "Understanding how is a field theory with a negative mass dimensional coupling becomes nonrenormalizable?". It does not say anything negative about effective theories.

Comment: @marmot I didn't say it was wrong. Not being entirely true means that it is true to a certain extent, but not fully, since there are exceptions as EFTs, for eg. we still use the Schrodinger equation for calculations despite it being non-renormalizable.

Comment: @OP - You might find the discussion on non-renormalizable theories in Matthew Schwartz's book (Chapter 22) to be relevant to your question